# Unexpected value 'FusionChartsModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, fusioncharts

how to add FusionChartsModule in app.module using angular 8 version.Below is my code:

```
    *error:Unexpected value 'FusionChartsModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please 
    add a @NgModule annotation. *,Getting this error in console code is compiling 
     successfully
```

these are my version details

Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FusioncharttestComponent } from './fusioncharttest/fusioncharttest.component';


import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';


// Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as FusionMaps from "fusionmaps/fusioncharts.maps";
import * as World from 'fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.world';

import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';


// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionMaps, FusionTheme, World);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FusioncharttestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FusionChartsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionMaps, FusionTheme, World) - should be in the imports I suspect..?

Comment: No actually this is the syntax I followed from fusion chart documentation ,the problem here is related to the FusionChartsModule that i have used inside imports array.

Comment: @RKS & R. Richards Please use angular-fusioncharts:3.0.4 to resolve the problem

Comment: @Zapdos13 yes I tried that still the same error. Please help

Comment: @RKS https://codesandbox.io/embed/angular-column3d-tlxtm?codemirror=1

Comment: @Zopdos13 yess this is working but its not working with angular cli 8.3.25 with same code

Comment: Please update the package.json and share the updated code @RKS

Comment: Anyone able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

I deleted the node modules & package-lock.json file and then install angular-fusioncharts: 3.0.4
Do not include ^ token in the version number

Answer (score 0):

Install the Angular-FusionCharts

```
$ npm install angular-fusioncharts --save
```

Import the Angular FusionCharts module

In the root Angular @NgModule import FusionChartsModule from angular-fusioncharts and add the FusionChartsModule as a dependency.

```
// Setup needed in app.module.ts

import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';

// Load FusionCharts
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
// Load Charts module
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
// Load fusion theme
import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

// Add dependencies to FusionChartsModule
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FusionChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Add the fusiocharts directive
In the template, add a  directive in the section where you wish to render the chart. We are assuming it's AppComponent which would change based on your usage.

Refer the doc - https://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/#/ex1